# Ruby How to merge to elements in a string array

Tags: ruby

My String array is something like this

```
arr = ["a", "apple", "b", "banyan", "banana", "c", "cat"]
```

I want merge baynan in to banana so my array look like this and I can create a hashmap

```
arr = ["a", "apple", "b", "banyanbanana", "c", "cat"]
hash_arr = Hash[*arr]
```

but still I do not have an idea to merge specific two adjacent value in the same array by ruby. there s no fixed position for the merge so that I can come out from the exception "odd number of arguments for Hash"

Thank you in advance

Comment: there s no fixed position for the merge - what do you mean? You want to merge indexes 3 and 4, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = ["a", "apple", "b", "banyan", "banana", "c", "cat"]

indexes = [3, 4] # Define which two elements to merge.

arr[indexes[0]] += arr.delete_at(indexes[1])

arr # => ["a", "apple", "b", "banyanbanana", "c", "cat"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. Im quite new to ruby :) recently moved from python still learning grammar :)

Comment: @Kalanamith: In that case, upvote his answer and mark it as accepted when the time limit allows it.

Answer (score 1):

So, for one value:

```
 arr = ["a", "apple", "b", "banyan", "banana", "c", "cat"]
 index = 3 # you can write `index = arr.find_index("banana")`
 arr[index..(index+1)] = arr[index] + arr[index+1]
```

You can use official ruby docs for learning which methods class supports: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html